# IISreset creates web.config under the wwwroot dir

Tags: security, iis, web-config, config, iisreset

IISreset creates web.config under the wwwroot dir.  Anyone know why this would happen?  it's creating a vulnerability.

thanks

Comment: Unless you can reproduce this on a clean machine (Windows built from original media), you can claim that you find some vulnerability. Otherwise, you have to check what you have installed there, which is often the real culprit.

Answer (score 0):

IIS should only generate web.config when it need to apply some configuration change in site level. Please check what was logged in that web.config and did you enable always running for your web application in Default Web Site.

Besides, Microsoft Prcocess monitor will display the process that created web.config.
Please create a filter for "Path contains wwwroot\web.config".

[image]
[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon